# debug .net library using HttpClient? (Get request hangs/time out)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, dotnet-httpclient, visual-studio-debugging

**Update/Edit**

I pull their repo build it and step through it, I find the HttpClient is simply timing out here

```
 var result = Await client.SendAsync(request) //Times out after a while
```

If i change it to a blocking call, it works

```
 var result = Await client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult() //Works
```

The next call, gets the results Async, and it works as expected

```
 var body = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //Works if the Send is synchronous
```

Why would sending the request Async timeout, yet performing the send blocking and then reading the result async work? I don't quite understand what is happening here?

**Original Post**

I'm struggling to debug an issue i'm facing using a 3rd party library that handles the HTTP requests to their API. I'm targeting .Net 4.6.1 - It's a mess of a web project with both WebApi and webforms.

The package is using HttpClient() for it's requests (Postmark.Net)

PostMark Package URL
https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-dotnet/tree/71c05efafd266a4403f8e6c18a8b485252082fd3

**Issue**
When I run the project, the application just appears to hang. It does not timeout and return back to the caller, it just appears stuck. In my debug window it just shows the threads exiting with code 0.

**Sample Code**

```
    Dim cc = New PostmarkDotNet.PostmarkClient("key")
    Dim msg = cc.GetOutboundMessageDetailsAsync("some-id").GetAwaiter.GetResult()
    Log.Debug(msg.Status.ToString & " - " & msg.ReceivedAt.ToString() & " - " & msg.To.FirstOrDefault.Email.ToString())
```

*Note: Intentionally using getAwaiter to block the thread to help troubleshoot.*

**What I've Tried:**

- Created a new .net project targeting the same framework version (4.7.1) - The library and code functions as expected; so it must be related to this project
- Clean / Rebuild the project
- Running Fiddler to see what is happening on the wire - i see an outbound request with a response with the SSL cert from the API - then nothing. I'm thinking perhaps some issue is occurring around the SSL handshake - however, i doubt it is a TLS issue since a test project on same machine worked as expected.

**Further Questions:**

- How can I debug or step into the library itself to see what is happening there?
- The package requires .Net.Http 4.3.4, but in my web.config i'm showing a bindingRedirect to 4.2.0.0, but in my test project i threw together seeing the same thing and not having an issue.
  Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong here, but my understanding would be "threads exiting with code 0" means that your app has simply done everything it was supposed to do and waiting on other events to process.